# Directly call an inline fun within Kotlin - Instead of inlining it

Tags: kotlin, inline

Consider following simple method:

```
inline fun foo(crossinline bar: () -> Unit) = foo(2) { bar() }
```

Now I'm trying to test this implementation:

```
@Test
fun `test foo`() {
    val action = mock<() -> Unit>()
    foo(action)
    verify(action)()
}
```

Since this test is written in *Kotlin* as well, the compiler inlines `foo` and with test coverage enabled the `foo()` *Java* method appears as not covered.

Now I'm wondering, how to configure the environment or the test to not inline functions in such cases?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. Inline functions are always inlined; many of their features depend on that, and you can't simply decide not to inline them.

The correct fix for this issue is to implement support for Kotlin inline functions in the coverage framework that you're using, so that it would realize that the function was indeed invoked. The .class files generated by the Kotlin compiler contain enough information for this.

The corresponding issue for jacoco is [here](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/654).

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood my findings, but wouldn't it be possible to implement the test in _Java_ to be able to call the functions directly without inlining?

Comment: Not all Kotlin inline functions can be called from Java, and not all of them work properly when you do call them (e.g. non-local returns will not work).